# Unsupported architecture error on initializing React Native app

Tags: ios, node.js, xcode, react-native, npm

It's so weird, yesterday morning everything works well, but after trying to install on a physical iOS device, I even cannot initiate a React Native project, right after the `npx react-native init MyNewApp` command I get this error:

```sh
clang: warning: using sysroot for 'iPhoneOS' but targeting 'MacOSX' [-Wincompatible-sysroot]
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/lib/libc++.tbd, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/lib/libc++.tbd (4 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd (4 slices)
clang: warning: using sysroot for 'iPhoneOS' but targeting 'MacOSX' [-Wincompatible-sysroot]
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:55:
In file included from /Users/amerllica/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.0/include/node/uv.h:52:
In file included from /Users/amerllica/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.0/include/node/uv/errno.h:25:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/errno.h:31:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/errno.h:23:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/sys/errno.h:72:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:807:2: error: Unsupported architecture
#error Unsupported architecture
 ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:55:
In file included from /Users/amerllica/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.0/include/node/uv.h:55:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdio.h:107:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: architecture not supported
#error architecture not supported
 ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:55:
In file included from /Users/amerllica/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.0/include/node/uv.h:55:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdio.h:107:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'; did you mean
      '__int128_t'?
typedef __int64_t       __darwin_blkcnt_t;      /* total blocks */
        ^
note: '__int128_t' declared here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean
      '__int128_t'?
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_blksize_t;     /* preferred block size */
        ^
note: '__int128_t' declared here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean
      '__int128_t'?
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_dev_t;         /* dev_t */
        ^
note: '__int128_t' declared here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean
      '__uint128_t'?
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_gid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
        ^
note: '__uint128_t' declared here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:61:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean
      '__uint128_t'?
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_id_t;          /* [XSI] pid_t, uid_t, or gid_t*/
        ^
note: '__uint128_t' declared here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:62:9: error: unknown type name '__uint64_t'; did you mean
      '__uint128_t'?
typedef __uint64_t      __darwin_ino64_t;       /* [???] Used for 64 bit inodes */
        ^
note: '__uint128_t' declared here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:68:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'
typedef __darwin_natural_t __darwin_mach_port_name_t; /* Used by mach */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:70:9: error: unknown type name '__uint16_t'; did you mean
      '__uint128_t'?
typedef __uint16_t      __darwin_mode_t;        /* [???] Some file attributes */
        ^
note: '__uint128_t' declared here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:71:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'; did you mean
      '__int128_t'?
typedef __int64_t       __darwin_off_t;         /* [???] Used for file sizes */
        ^
note: '__int128_t' declared here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:72:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean
      '__int128_t'?
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_pid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
        ^
note: '__int128_t' declared here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:73:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean
      '__uint128_t'?
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_sigset_t;      /* [???] signal set */
        ^
note: '__uint128_t' declared here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:74:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean
      '__int128_t'?
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_suseconds_t;   /* [???] microseconds */
        ^
note: '__int128_t' declared here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:75:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean
      '__uint128_t'?
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_uid_t;         /* [???] user IDs */
        ^
note: '__uint128_t' declared here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean
      '__uint128_t'?
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_useconds_t;    /* [???] microseconds */
        ^
note: '__uint128_t' declared here
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:55:
In file included from /Users/amerllica/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.0/include/node/uv.h:55:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdio.h:107:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:43:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean
      '__uint128_t'?
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_wctype_t;
        ^
note: '__uint128_t' declared here
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:55:
In file included from /Users/amerllica/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.0/include/node/uv.h:55:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdio.h:107:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:75:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_va_list.h:31:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/machine/types.h:37:2: error: architecture not supported
#error architecture not supported
 ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:55:
In file included from /Users/amerllica/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.0/include/node/uv.h:55:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdio.h:107:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:75:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_va_list.h:32:9: error: unknown type name
      '__darwin_va_list'
typedef __darwin_va_list va_list;
        ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/amerllica/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/amerllica/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.0/bin/node" "/Users/amerllica/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/amerllica/.npm/_npx/15892/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v12.18.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

I tried many ways, even I uninstall XCode and then re-install XCode. set everything from scratch but I get this error for initializing React Native application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following steps everything back on track:

1. Logging out
2. Restarting

It's so weird, but fully shut down the system without keeping open programs states was the solution.